# Modifying group type and scope in Active directory through Perl LDAP

Tags: perl, active-directory, ldap

In Active directory existing groups can be specified in the following ways

**Type:** Distribution and Security

**Scope:** Global, Domain Local and Universal

Is there a way to modify this in some way using something from the LDAP library of perl since I can not find anything related to this property in the methods of the LDAP.

Answer (score 1):

No knowledge on perl LDAP library.
Can you update the groupType attribute directly?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675935%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

See the Remarks section.

2 (0x00000002): global scope
4 (0x00000004): domain local scope
8 (0x00000008):  universal scope
2147483648 (0x80000000): security group if this bit is set, otherwise distribution group

Comment: I suppose I can the problem is that I can't find a possible way to access this group type information.

I'm also able to change this things directly but there are thousands of groups to go through and groups keep been created as they are needed automatically. The changing of those type is needed for further automation for granting all the permissions related to those groups.